# lxml XSD processing reports that empty string does not match a regex which it should match. Why?

Tags: xml, regex, xsd, lxml

I am trying to validate a document given an xsd file, with lxml in Python:

```
from lxml import etree

xmlschema_doc = etree.parse('somefile.xsd')
xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
xml_doc = etree.parse('somefile.xml')

xmlschema.assertValid(xml_doc)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
lxml.etree.DocumentInvalid: Element 'someelement': [facet 'pattern'] The value '' is not accepted by the pattern '\s*.{0,10}\s*'., line 24
```

Line 24 is:

```
<someelement></somelement>
```

Which is specified in my XSD file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
    <xs:simpleType name="someelement">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\s*.{0,10}\s*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

What is weird here is that the empty string should be valid for the pattern `\s*.{0,10}\s*`

Do you have any explanation ?

Edit: Adds XSD definition of someelement and removes reference to python re

Comment: By the way (but that's probably not the source of the error), you should always use raw strings for regexes if they contain backslashes. `\s` happens to work, but `\b` for example will fail (because it will be interpreted as a backspace character, not a word boundary).

Comment: You should probably show your XSD if you want help with this beyond what I have told you.

Comment: Also, try `[\s]*.{0,10}[\s]*`

Comment: Marcin: the XSD file was given to me by the third party I need to communicate with along with an example of XML file that it should validate (but it doesn't). I cannot expose publicly those files, that's why I only copied the interesting part.

With your pattern I still get the same error:
The value '' is not accepted by the pattern '[\s]*.{0,10}[\s]*'

Comment: Found a similar problem here: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2011-August/msg00014.html

Answer (score 0):

XSD is a separate standard from python. Your patterns in an XSD file need to conform to XSD syntax.

The official definition of an XSD regex is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#dt-regex

Comment: So what should it look like then?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: What part of "Should conform to XSD syntax" is unclear? I'm not going to write this guy's code for him.

Comment: I'm just curious. So XSD does not use regular expressions? (You can tell I have no idea about XSD)

Comment: Marcin, what would be useful would be to mention what differs between XSD regex and Python regex that makes '' not valid for the pattern '\s*.{0,10}\s*' ? It would be interesting to know if this is not a lxml specific problem.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: It does use regular expressions, but python didn't invent regular expressions. Just because something is a python RE it doesn't follow it's a valid RE, or an RE with the same behaviour in another RE implementation.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm sure you would find that useful. Maybe google a tutorial, or look at the standard.

Comment: According to the page you linked, that regex should be perfectly valid as an XSD regex. Your answer is not very helpful.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: You don't think being told to use the right standard, instead of an incorrect one, is useful?

Comment: As far as I can tell, he *is*  using the right standard. Where exactly is his regex not correct according to the standard you linked to? What am I missing?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: He is testing for correctness of his regex (or demonstrating it) using the python regex facility. He might as well use the emacs regex facility - just because they are similar, it doesn't mean that they are the same. As it happens, I'm surprised that this isn't doing what is expected. In any case, the place to start looking for the answer is not in some generic notion of regexes, *it is in the actual standard for regexes that applies*, and then in the implementation if it appears to be non-conforming.

Comment: Well I removed all about python re from my post. Anyway my regex should validate the string, it might be a problem with lxml ...

Comment: @Thomas: It might be, but I wouldn't bet on that as your first call. Maybe...find something else that processes XSD regexes, or xsd, and try with that. Or maybe you could even post your XSD if you want someone to help you with it.

Comment: What is the pattern.. u would lik to have? plz elaborate

Answer (score 0):

in your regex, remove the \s so that it looks like

```
<xs:pattern value="*.{0,10}*"/>
```

I have used

```
<xsd:pattern value="(Pattern|.{0})"/>
```

in order to match a pattern or blank.